# Unable to click on list button option in selenium : Exception Element not visible

Tags: selenium

Hi I am trying to select on the list option cold and Flu but I am getting Element not visible exception, Can someone please help me how to select it in selenium script.

Site URL : http://www.healthdirect.gov.au/symptom-checker/tool?symptom=COLD

Colds and flu

Here is my selenium code

```
public void selectspecificSymptom(String arg) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg.toLowerCase())
    {
    case "cold and flu":

    /*  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-true-value='49|Feeling sick or unwell|1']"));
        actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
        actions.click();
        actions.perform();*/

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-true-value='49|Feeling sick or unwell|1']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("submitAnswer"));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Not a valid option");
        break;
    }   


}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep? Also, your xpath is to select *Feeling sick or unwell* and not *Colds and flu*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
public class Stack{

    @Test public static void select() throws InterruptedException{

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://www.healthdirect.gov.au/symptom-checker/tool");

            //wait for the iframe and switch

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            WebElement frame = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'easyXDM_default')]")));
            driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
            Thread.sleep(11000);

            //Get all your health topics and select one which matches

            List<WebElement> l = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='leftCol']/div/button"));

            for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(l.get(i).getText());
                    if (l.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Ear, nose and throat")){
                        l.get(i).click();
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        //Get all your symptoms and select the needed

                        List<WebElement> l1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentHeight']/div[2]/button"));
                        //Place your second for loop for the second list here
                        l1.get(1).click(); //just to test your 'Colds and flu' link

                    }
            }
```

---

**Notes:**

- You have have one iframe over there, So you need to switch to that before you want to click on your element
- I had a very bad internet when i was trying, so adjust your thread.sleeep() or wait for the element with explicit waits
- Do remember to switch back from the iframe if you want to operate outside